# How to get value from attribute of h1 tag using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a sample code:

```
<h1 class="test" idtest="1">Test 1</h1>
<h1 class="test" idtest="2">Test 2</h1>

And jquery:
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $('.test').click(function (){
      var id = $('.test').attr('idtest') ; 
      alert(id);
   })
});
```

How to fix it to get value from h1

Answer (score 5):

use the `data` attribute and use `$(this)` instead of `$('.test')` inside the click function.

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/xe7gC/)*

```
<h1 class="test" data-idtest="1">Test 1</h1>
<h1 class="test" data-idtest="2">Test 2</h1>
```

And jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $('.test').click(function (){
      var id = $(this).data('idtest') ;  
      alert(id);
   })
});
```

Read more here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Answer (score 0):

you mean like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rZcqD/2/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/rZcqD/4/

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $('.test').click(function (){
      var id = $(this).attr('idtest') ; 
      alert($(this).text());
   })
});​
```

Comment: `:))` Brilliant - lol and Downvote because? any explanation? or just random dislike `:)`

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I think op wants to show 1 and 2 not Test 1 and Test 2.

Comment: Hiya @mprabhat Thanks `:)` but for the Downvoter -  OPs code work http://jsfiddle.net/rZcqD/4/ ( just *this* ref is missing).

Answer (score 0):

Use $(this) inside the click() handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $('.test').click(function (){
      var id = $(this).attr('idtest') ; 
      alert(id);
   })
});
```